# Как сделать невозможным удаление с сайта  копирайта?

Tags: авторские-права, php, html

Возникла проблема - нет гарантии, что после получения исходников сайта заказчик не удалит копирайт студии. Какие есть варианты защиты? Желательно, с намеками на способы реализации.

Comment: backdoor, оговорка в контракте или привязка движка к копирайту.

    if(strpos($cprt, 'mysite.ru') === false) die();

Comment: Бэкдор точно не вариант, т.к. на cms собрано много сайтов - возможность угона более чем не желательна. Контракт ни от чего не спасает. А последний вариант легко обходится банальным style="display:none;".

Comment: Простите, у вас нет гарантии что заказчик **может** удалить копирайт?

Comment: В данном случае, на мой взгляд, нужно как-то минимально скрыть в коде копирайт и четко написать в договоре, о том, что удалять его нельзя. Ибо если кто-то задастся целью - он его удалит. Кстати, я так думаю, что можно еще поставить какой-нибудь движок, который, скажем, раз в сутки будет парсером чекать копирайты на ваших сайтах.

Comment: Кстати, кроме фактического присутствия копирайта, не забудьте сделать проверку, не скрыт ли он с помощью обычного `css` (`{display:none}` или `{visibility:hidden}`), или же `javascript` (просто удалить копирайт после загрузки) и т.д.

Comment: @ImirofF, вы решили мне мстить за закрытый по трем тревогам вопрос?) Не рекомендую :)

Answer (score 2):

Смотри про [Zend](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend)

> Zend Optimizer — Являет собой
> серверный модуль для запуска
> закодированных с помощью Zend Encoder
> и Zend SafeGuard Suite скриптов, а
> также немного их ускоряющий (заявлено,
> что до 40%).
>
> Zend Guard (ранее назывался Zend
> Encoder) — позволяет закодировать
> скрипт в байт-код, который потом можно
> использовать точно также как и
> обычный, за исключением возможности
> его отредактировать. Предназначено для
> защиты интересов и интеллектуальной
> собственности разработчика. Для работы
> таких скриптов обязательно нужен Zend
> Optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

Если предположить, что заказчик не очень умен в php, то можно прибегнуть к шифрованию участка кода в котором будет находиться копирайт. Еще есть вариант написать код автоматического удаленного контроля за ссылкой.

Answer (score 1):

Можно запутать заказчика. Напишите функцию, которая будет выводить текст копирайта. Запишите в ней строку копирайта в неявном виде, например в шестнадцатеричном формате, например:

```
$copy = "\061\060\x32\x35";
```

Назовите функцию так чтобы она не намекала на копирайты и вызывайте ее анонимно или через переменную:

```
$func = 'foo';  
$func();
```

Конечно это сработает если заказчик нуб)

Answer (score 0):

Может, как вариант, предоставить все исходники кроме файла, который инклудится в каждую страничку проекта и содержит обязательные переменные для полноценного функционирования всего сайта и копирайт в том числе. А сам файл хранить на своем сервере.
Еще, возможно, как вариант, каждую функцию завязать на проверку переменной, равной base64-коду картинки-копирайта. Заказчику дороже обойдется переписывание всех функций для избавления от этого, чем смириться с тем, что автор открыто заявляет о своем труде.

Comment: У меня уйдет около 2 минут на написание скрипта удаления этого куска из всех функций)

Comment: А если использовать обфускатор?